# Sun Ultra 24 compatible components - PC self build

Tags: motherboard, atx

I'm considering buying a Sun Ultra 24 workstation case, however I'd like to know the limitation of such a case.  Such as;

- Compatible motherboards, and whether a full length pci-x express board would fit in.
- Will it take any off the shelf power supply?
- How to hook up the firewire and USB ports on the front of the case.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not every used one before, but after reading some specs, it looks like it's compatible with standard components, especially:

1. full length video cards
2. off the self power supply
3. USB and firewire hookups

However, I would be afraid to say with 100% certainty that it takes standard motherboards, but I'd be surprised if you couldn't fit an off the self motherboard in there.

Here are the specs I read:

- [Sun Ultra 24 Workstation Product Notes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19127-01/ultra24.ws/820-2480-12/820-2480-12.pdf)
- [Sun Ultra 24 Workstation Installation Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19127-01/ultra24.ws/820-2475-10/820-2475-10.pdf)
- [Sun Microsystems Ultra 24 Workstation - Techworld](http://review.techworld.com/operating-systems/570/sun-microsystems-ultra-24-workstation/)